I need help formatting this code as a Ruby method
So, I have passing code for what I am trying to achieve. Now I need to format it in a method format that takes two parameters. I have more experience with JavaScript functions at this point and am still really new to the Ruby format. I want the method to look like this more or less:
substrings("word", dictionary)
and have it output a hash with the key being the "word" and the value being the number of times that unique string was found in the array.
When I try writing it as a method, here is an example of the errors I get:
unexpected string literal; expected a ) to close the parametersunexpected ',', expecting end-of-inputunexpected ',', ignoring itunexpected ')', expecting end-of-inputunexpected ')', ignoring it
>  7    def substrings("word", library)
> 15  end 

script.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected string literal, expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
  def substrings("word", library) 

I just have been getting errors when I try putting it in a def ... end block. Honestly, I just need help on knowing how to format this as a method (or to be pointed to literature to help me grasp the concept better) thank you for any insight.
I have logic that I found from a great article:
https://medium.com/@imanj12/counting-array-elements-made-simple-using-rubys-each-with-object-method-and-hash-class-f0ff80852cdd#:~:text=Side%2Dnote:%20the%20above%20hash,short%2C%20it%20functions%20exactly%20like%20
here is the logic (which works as expected)
library = ["below","down","go","going","horn","how","howdy","it","i","low","own","part", "part", "partner", "sit", "low", "go", "go",] 
  
string_count = library.each_with_object (Hash.new (0)) do |word, new_hash|
  new_hash[word] += 1
end

 puts string_count 

my attempt to write it as a method:
 def substrings("word", library)
  library = ["below","down","go","going","horn","how","howdy","it","i","low","own","part", "part", "partner","sit", "low", "go", "go", ] 
  
string_count = library.each_with_object (Hash.new (0)) do |word, new_hash|
  new_hash[word] += 1
end

 puts string_count
end 
substrings("go", library) ``` 


What have you tried? What errors are you getting? Here are the syntax documents for Methods and Calling Methods

thank you for commenting with those links. I will read them and see if I can navigate to the solution. I know this is a very basic concept so I will work to figure it out with that info, thank you.

In Ruby, the return value of a method with no return keyword is the return value of the last statement in the method. Your last statement is puts string_count, which prints the string count, then returns nil. Therefore, your method returns nil.
If you want it to return string_count, you should have string_count on the last line of the method by itself. If you want it printed, you can still have that in your method; it just can't be on the last line. In your case, though, it looks like you don't really want the count for every word returned, just for a particular target word, so you have to ask for that word after the hash object is populated.
(Also, you can't use a string literal (like "word") as an argument parameter, which is why def substrings("word", library) is a syntax error.)
Here's one way you could do it:
def substrings(target_word, library)  
  string_count = library.each_with_object (Hash.new (0)) do |word, new_hash|
    new_hash[word] += 1
  end

  puts string_count

  string_count.slice(target_word)
end

library = ["below","down","go","going","horn","how","howdy","it","i","low","own","part", "part", "partner","sit", "low", "go", "go"]
string_count_for_go = substrings("go", library)
puts string_count_for_go

Here is the relevant documentation for why Hash.slice returns what you are asking for.

I greatly appreciate your input. While that makes sense and works, I need the method to take two arguments: the word (or words) that we want the values of and the dictionary. I will continue to try solving it with the direction you gave. Thank you

@JessicaYeverino I think I already made that change—try refreshing the page?

oh thank you; I see the edit now. That makes a lot of sense about the string literal throwing an error in my code. Thank you for your contribution; I hope to get more skilled with writing methods as I study. at the end, is the string_count_for_go just an example?

It is just an example, yes. I wrote it using your existing code, which counts every string and puts those counts into a hash, and then I simply asked the hash for the value associated with the target word. As such, the method returns only the count. (In this case, 3.) I notice your question asked for a hash. I will amend the method to return (e.g.) {"go" => 3} instead, though I'm not sure why you'd want it that way.

@JessicaYeverino I've made that change now. If you want it the other way, change .slice back to the [] operator, i.e. string_count[target_word].

thank you for working through the problem and showing me how it's done. I am working through a course that wants a hash to be returned from the method so that's why I'm looking for the hash result. Thank you for your attention to detail. I will learn from this going forward.

Great! In that case, I've added a link to Ruby documentation showing how the slice method works here.

@engineersmnky I know there are better ways to write this code but I figured it made sense to use the code as written, given the nature of the question. I didn't know about tally though, which is nice. Thanks!

I have my code matching yours now. I am receiving a NoMethodError (I think due to string count being in the method and then being used outside of the method on string_count_for_go) I will work on it and see if i can make it return the expected result.
